# How do you make tqdm give the correct speed estimate when using an initial counter value which is not zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I'm trying to show a progress bar for a process that was previously interrupted and was resumed. The progress bar needs to start partially filled, showing what has been completed before interruption. I'm using the "initial" parameter to set what has been completed.

However, the speed being shown is the total amount of iterations completed, including those that set in initial, divided by the time elapsed during this run, which gives an underestimation of the actual speed. Is there a way to make tqdm ignore the iterations it was initialised with when calculating the speed?

Here is a minimal reproducable code:

```
import tqdm
import time

prog = tqdm.tqdm(initial=50, total=100, smoothing=0.0)
for _ in range(50, 100):
   time.sleep(1)
   prog.update(1)
   prog.refresh()
prog.close()
```

Comment: Found this as a Github issue: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/689

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have set the smoothing to 0 set the smoothing 1 and you will get the correct iteration speed or you can even set it to default without sending the value of smoothing and you will get the exact iteration speed

Here is the code:

```
import tqdm
import time

prog = tqdm.tqdm(initial=50, total=100)
for _ in range(50, 100):
   time.sleep(1)
   prog.update(1)
   prog.refresh()
prog.close()
```

Comment: This will show correct iteration speed when the progress bar is running.

Comment: Are you talking about the final iteration speed that is displayed???? please let me know

Comment: Won't that show just the last iteration's speed? I need to get the average speed of all the iterations that I ran.

Comment: To be honest i tried a lot of methods and it is not possible to do so it is a bug in the tqdm package there are 2 things that you can do.1. Make changes to tqdm package and fix the error. 2. Calculate the iteration speed your self.